# Send formatted tweets on twitter : iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to send detailed information in tweet on twitter. So can i add html tags to show that message? Is there any way to send detailed information in [_engine sendUpdate:xyz]; ??

Answer (score 2):

Twitter does not support rich text messages. You're allow 140 of plain text.